# Create Drupal users with custom usernames from Company Data?

Tags: drupal, user-account

In my company members have a unique membership ID. Is it possible, that the Drupal users which are created by CiviCRM, can have this membership ID as the username and not the real name/email address as is used currently?

We would also like to use the members' date of birth as their password and set this automatically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if CiviRules allows the creation of a CMS user when a membership is created. But you could write a small extension that implements a hook to override the username (to use the member ID) and password (to use the Date of Birth) or implement a hook (post on membership) to create a CMS user when a membership is purchased (created),

Comment: CiviRules doesn't have a "Create CMS User" rule - unless you install my [Silent User Registration](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/silentuserreg) extension :)

Answer (score 0):

Other option would be to look at what Drupal Rules can do